# Should I change the value of a function parameter?

Tags: c++, c, function, parameters

I know that this is allowed in C, but I am used not to update the value of a variable passed by value.

In my "coding style", a parameter passed by value is not changed.
I mean that I prefer this:

```
void func(int var)
{
    int locVar = var;

    if(something)
    {
        locVar = locVar/2;
    }

    // [some stuff using locVar]
}
```

over this:

```
void func(int var)
{
    if(something)
    {
        var = var/2;
    }

    // [some stuff using var]
}
```

I assume that the compiler will not produce different assembly if the register optimizations are enabled, **but still, is there any good reason to prefer one of the two code snippets?**

Comment: Yes, modifying parameters is little bit more error prone. Also in debug you won't know what's original value of a parameter but its actual value. You're not doing #1 (correctly) because of compiler and/or performance but for yourself.

Comment: IMO changing parameters is not bad coding style. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: @Plouff The only reason to use the first approach is when the original value is used several times. Otherwise there is no need to introduce a new local variable. Function parameters are already its local variables.

Comment: There is no reason for concern. Compiler will create new variable on stack and copy value threre.

Comment: IMNVHO it's more robust and future-proof to declare all input variables as `const` and use local variables if you need a modified version of an input parameter (i.e. your first example above, but defined as `void func(const int var)`)

Comment: @AlexanderVaganov By the way a function can have numerous parameters. Will you rename all of them in the function by introducing new local variables?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow The comment was about selecting second option.

Comment: It is purely a matter of coding style.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I would tend to create copies of all the parameters I want to change - there are usually very few of those.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Remove "stupidity", it's my trademark.

Comment: @MartinBonner For starters for readers of the code it will not be clear that you introduced the new variables just to support your own coding style:) It can be confusing.

Comment: It is interesting to see that this is a matter of habits actually!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Would you agree with the solution below? When I read your comment I felt like I was totally in line with the reasons you gave. But there is no consensus actually! It's a bit disturbing...

Comment: You should modify expensive to copy types that are passed by value if you intend to return it or store it, so you get a move instead of a copy. Since the question has been closed, I can't provide that in an answer.

Comment: @NikosC.: Thanks for your comments. It's a very interesting approach to keep in mind the weight of the copy. I'll remember that!

Answer (score 1):

No.

- From a computers point of view - no difference. Optimization will do the job.
- From a personal point of view - a matter of taste
- From a meta-view - do not set up pitfalls

Very often initial parameter values are needed multiple times in a function, the more common style therefore is not to overwrite parameters. It is very convenient to have the values available for debugging, logging messages (“wrote n bytes”), in catch clauses and so on. As this is more or less common style, a maintainer could easily miss your itsy-bitsy-premature-optimization. Such optimizations were common in the age of non-optimizing C compilers, nowadays they are just 'because-I-can' stuff. Remember, we write code to be readable by humans. Compilers can do that anyway.

Comment: These are exactly the reasons why I never modified parameter variables. I would never have thought this would such a matter of taste!

Answer (score 1):

> is there any good reason to prefer one of the two code snippets?

1) Compilers are not created equal.  `int locVar = var;` *may* create faster code.  (I was surprise to find this true in a given application.)  This is local or micro-optimization and is only useful in select cases and of course may result is different performance when compiled with other options or on another machine.

2) Less is better.  Introducing a synonym as in `int locVar = var;`is more code and more variables to understand and maintain.  *Usually* this is less helpful.

3) Both code snippets generate valid code.  So this is a style issue too.  If your coding group has a coding guideline concerning this, better to follow that than be different for trivial reasons.

Select reasons to prefer one over the other: Yes.  Strong reasons: In general no.  When in doubt of which way to go, the easy to maintain one wins outs (IMO).

Comment: So to sum up, you would not use extra variable unless required by a coding guideline or in rare cases as an optimization for some compilers. I wouldn't have considered that copying variables would cause an overhead in terms of maintainability. It's an interesting point of view!

Answer (score 0):

In general the more variables are introduced the less readable and more complicated the code will be.

Sometimes it is even difficult to invent two names for one entity that semantically they would look identically.

For example a function listing can occupy several screens. In this case if you encountered a name like `locVar`  you need to scroll the function listing backward to determine what this name means.

Moreover a function can have several parameters. Are you going to introduce new aliases for each parameter?

For readers of your code it will not be clear that you introduced new local variables just to support your coding style. They for example can think that you changed the function and forgot to remove variables that are not necessary any more.:)

Consider for example a recursive function that calculates the sum of digits of a number.

```
unsigned int sum( unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    unsigned int digit = x % Base;
    return digit + ( ( x /= Base ) == 0 ? 0 : sum( x ) );
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

or that can be written like

```
unsigned int sum( unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    return x % Base + ( x / Base == 0 ? 0 : sum( x / Base ) );
}
```

What is the purpose to introduce a new local variable as an alias of `x` in this function?

```
unsigned int sum( unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    unsigned int y = x;
    unsigned int digit = y % Base;
    return digit + ( ( y /= Base ) == 0 ? 0 : sum( y ) );
}
```

As for me then the first function implementation without the intermediate variable `y` is more clear. The recursive nature of the function is more visible when the same variable `x` is used.

If you want to point out that a parameter is not changed in a function you can declare or define the function with the parameter that has qualifier const.

For example

```
unsigned int sum( const unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    return x % Base + ( x / Base == 0 ? 0 : sum( x / Base ) );
}
```

In C++ function calls could look like

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr unsigned int sum( const unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    return x % Base + ( x / Base == 0 ? 0 : sum( x / Base ) );
} 

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum( 123456789 ) << std::endl;
    int a[sum( 123456789 )];

    std::cout << sizeof( a ) << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
45
180
```

Comment: Your first example is not compelling; it doesn't assign to the function parameter anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have not understood what you mean by the first example?

Comment: I mean that the question is about modifying the value of a function parameter by assignment, but your code does not assign to the function parameter.  It is hard to come up with a good example quickly, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks now I have understood. I will update my example.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Thank for this detailed answer. So in you opinion it is better to use `const` than to make a copy of all the parameters. It makes sense... I need to get used to that!

Comment: @Plouff Sometimes introducing a new local variable that equal to a parameter arises a question why was it done so?L)

Comment: Using const is always a good idea.  I would write Vlad's example as `const auto x1 = x/10; return x%10 + (x1==0)?0:sum(x1);`  To me using x/=10 is just reusing the variable name for a completely different value.  It also makes me double check the code to ensure that the sequencing is correct (in fact it is).  Lots of variables, each of them const is my style.

Comment: @MartinBonner: So this is really a matter of taste here. I think that I would do like you!

Comment: Your first example is a very good example for a satanically hidden modification of a parameter which IMHO is a no-go already. BTW - isn't that undefined behaviour? Your third example takes the wrong approach, the local variable would be a `const unsigned int quotient = x / Base;`

Comment: @stefan It seems you are a beginner.:) All the code in my post is valid.:) No additional variables are required.:0

Comment: IMHO the modification `x/=Base` and the evaluation `x%Base` are unsequenced.

Comment: @stefan Oh, It seems you are right! It is my mistake.:) Thanks. It is a good remark.:)

Comment: You have to make your sum function constexpr. Valarrays aren't in C++.

Comment: @Vincent It is a constexpr function is not it?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sry looked at the examples above.